# Hyper-V RDP image viewing lags

Tags: hyper-v, rdp

I really need some help with hyper-v and RDP connection issue.

**SCOPE:**

- SERVER (dedicated): Xeon E3-1230V2 (3.3 GHz), Intel S1200BTLR, RAM 32 Gb;
- HOST OS: windows server 2012 64-bit;
- VM OS (hyper-v): windows server 2003 32-bit (terminal server);
- HOST COMPANY: Hetzner.de.

**PROBLEM:** we experience some kind of lags when connecting to VM OS through RDP (cross country but host company and internet providers say that everything is ok with trace):

- viewing images and pdf - slow (windows image viewer says "generating preview" for 20 seconds);
- browsing web - slow;
- connecting and logging in - fast;
- browsing through folders and files - fast;
- host os has no lags when viewing images or PDFs.

**DETAILS:**

- network: HOST-OS (main ip) -> VM OS (direct ip from subnet which routing with IPEnableRouter registry option on the host like in hetzner manual http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Windows_Server_2012_Subnet/en;
- if vm os is server 2008 or 2012 viewing images still lags but is better than in 2003;
- if vm os is windows 7 or windows 8 with remotefx - we have no lags when viewing images.

Can somebody help to solve this issue or give any hints?
I can provide more details if needed.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You are done. No chance to fix it.

- 2008 and 2012 did improove the RDP protocol significantly, hence no lag.
- Unless you use RemoteFx there is no graphics acceleration worth mentioning on the server. THis simply is not feasible for anything heavily visual. I suggest you open a web browser, go to a page with some animation and watch in shock as nothing is uable anymore.

Best chance is to retire the seriosly outdated 32 bit terminal and go for something sensible. A VDI infrastructure (WIn 8 VM's with remotefx) may also be needed. I do not consider this fixable given the technology selection you did. Alternatively putting some WAN compressor in may help. You simply are way outside what the RDP scenarios of that ancient time are supposed to suppot.